# Caret and GBM Errors

Tags: r, r-caret

I am attempting to use the `caret` package in R for several nested cross-validation processes with user-defined performance metrics. I have had all kinds of problems, so I pulled back to see see if there were issues with a more out of the box use of `caret` and it seems I have run into one.

If  I run the following:

```
install.packages("caret")
install.packages("gbm")
library(caret)
library(gbm)


data(GermanCredit)
GermanCredit$Class<-ifelse(GermanCredit$Class=='Bad',1,0)



gbmGrid <- expand.grid(.interaction.depth = 1,
                       .n.trees = 150,
                       .shrinkage = 0.1)


  
   gbmMOD <- train(Class~., data=GermanCredit
                ,method = "gbm",
             tuneGrid= gbmGrid,
                distribution="bernoulli",
                bag.fraction = 0.5, 
                train.fraction = 0.5, 
                n.minobsinnode = 10, 
                cv.folds = 1, 
                keep.data=TRUE,
                verbose=TRUE
                
)
```

I get the error (or similar):

> Error in { :
> task 1 failed - "arguments imply differing number of rows: 619, 381"

with warnings:

```
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Resample01: interaction.depth=1, n.trees=150, shrinkage=0.1
```

But, if I run just the gbm routine everything finishes fine.

```
gbm1 <- gbm(Class~., data=GermanCredit,
            distribution="bernoulli",
            n.trees=150, # number of trees
            shrinkage=0.10, 
            interaction.depth=1, 
            bag.fraction = 0.5,
            train.fraction = 0.5, 
            n.minobsinnode = 10, 
            cv.folds = 1, 
            keep.data=TRUE, 
            verbose=TRUE
)
```

Comment: I have found that the error is raised when the argument cv.folds=1 is added. cv.folds should be passed to gbm, but it is causing an error for some reason. cv.folds=0 is the default of gbm anyway (which should give the same result as cv.folds=1).

Comment: The usual method of addressing suspected bugs is to contact the package maintainer

Comment: After posting the question I figured out where the error was coming from and will email Max Kuhn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two issues: passing `cv.folds` caused a problem. Also, you don't need to convert the outcome to a binary number; this causes `train` to think that it is a regression problem. The idea behind the `train` function is to smooth out the inconsistencies with the modeling functions, so we use factors for classification and numbers for regression.

Answer (score 0):

Just for note - although this issue has been caused by the reason described in the answer, the error message (given below) may also occur with older version of caret and gbm. I encountered this error and after spending a lot of time trying to figure out what the issue was it turned out that I had to upgrade to the most recent version of caret (5.17-7) and gbm (2.1-0.1). These are the most recent version as of today on CRAN.

```
Error in { : 
task 1 failed - "arguments imply differing number of rows: ...
```